# create multiple instances with one snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

everyone. I'm a fresh to use GCP. I have a request, I need to create several compute engine instances with one snapshot at the same time.
I found out instance group could create several instances by using instance templates. But it seems can't use snapshots. I need bunch of severs run the same software which I've already saved as a snapshot.
Is there any solutions that can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps will guide you through the process.

**Step 1:** "CREATE SNAPSHOT" of the disk. Skip this step if one already exists.

[image]

**Step 2:** "CREATE AN IMAGE" with the Snapshot as follows: 
[image]

**Step 3:** "CREATE AN INSTANCE GROUP TEMPLATE". Under the boot disk section, click **"change"**, under the:

> Select an image to create a boot disk. The image determines the operating system installed on the instance.

Select **"Custom images"** and tick the image to use for your template.

[image]

**Step 4:** "CREATE INSTANCE GROUP" with the newly created instance template; define your desired number of instances to create the instance number.

[image]